# counting the number of documents containing a specific term

Tags: java

```
File folder2 = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer");

File[] listOfFiles2 = folder.listFiles(); 
System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String word2 = scan.nextLine();
    String [] array2 = word2.split(" ");



{
for (int i=0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
{
  if ((listOfFiles2[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")))
  {

      try
      {
      BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listOfFiles2[i].getName()));

      int numDoc = 0;

      Scanner s2 = new Scanner(listOfFiles2[i].getName());
      {
          while (s2.hasNext())
          {
              if (s2.next().equals(word2)) numDoc++;
          }

            System.out.println("The number of document containing the term is " + numDoc);

        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

This is my code for counting the number of documents that contain a specific term.
Every time the program finds a specific term inside the document, it will increment numDoc counter.
This code does not do anything, however. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is Java best suited for that? :-S

Comment: If you added some debug prints to your code I think it would aid you in solving your problem.

Comment: It surely does something:) Try to debug it. You should be able to cope with it on your own.

Comment: it doesnt shows anything..which makes me ponder which part is missing...

Comment: in the line `for (int i=0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)`, do you really use the array listOfFiles or this is a typo and you meant listOfFiles2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add System.out.println() throughout your code to output important information for debugging.
2. Not directly related but you can use a enhance for loop to loop through the files.  See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html
3. Your System.out.println for your total is inside your loop and it should be outside after you have finished looping through all the documents.
4. **(And maybe the most important)** You are not handling your IOException.  At the least printout a stack trace or the message from the exception.